# Extjs - url navigation

Tags: extjs

Extjs prefers your app to be a single page app, but I'd still like to be able to do things like refresh my page and keep my current location in the app, and enter a url to get directly to a particular point in the app. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Could you test if the answer below works for you?

Comment: It's sitting at the top of my priority list, but of course new things keep coming my way. I will report back when I've tested it (hopefully in the next day or 2). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I do the same in my app. You can use the Ext JS history mechanism to do so. Have a look at [this example from Sencha](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/history/history.html#main-tabs%3atab1).

You can listen to the history change event like this

```
Ext.History.on('change', function(token) {
    // you navigate-to-target code goes here, e.g. change the viewport content
}
```

You can then initiate navigation by setting the browser hash to some navigation target

```
document.location.hash = yourNavigationToken;
```

This gives you also the ability to use deep-linking and forward/backward navigation with the browser buttons.

You need to init the history:

```
// The only requirement for this to work is that you must have a hidden field and
// an iframe available in the page with ids corresponding to Ext.History.fieldId
// and Ext.History.iframeId.  See history.html for an example.
Ext.History.init();
```

and add an iframe and a hidden input field to your page, like in the example:

```
<form id="history-form" class="x-hide-display">
    <input type="hidden" id="x-history-field" />
    <iframe id="x-history-frame"></iframe>
</form>
```